# MobileFirst Push notification fails after an adapter call

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working in a hybrid Mobile First app for android, and after I call an adapter the callback function registered never get call. Here is the log, all I can see is that my app is unregistering the push subscriptions.

```
05-06 11:18:16.429: D/mali_winsys(4021): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
05-06 11:18:16.429: D/ProgressBar(4021): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
05-06 11:18:16.429: D/ProgressBar(4021): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
05-06 11:18:16.429: D/ProgressBar(4021): updateDrawableBounds: right = 144
05-06 11:18:16.429: D/ProgressBar(4021): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 144
05-06 11:18:16.479: D/NONE(4021): Request [/apps/services/api/appname/android/query]
05-06 11:18:16.574: D/HttpPostRequestSender(4021): WLHybridRequestSender.run in WLHybridRequestSender.java:47 :: Sending request https://domain/appproject/apps/services/api/appname/android/query
05-06 11:18:16.574: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):getSBService() is false
05-06 11:18:16.574: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):SMARTBONDING_ENABLED is false
05-06 11:18:16.574: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):Resquest instance of HttpUriRequesttrue
05-06 11:18:16.574: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):determineRoute Local address : null
05-06 11:18:16.579: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):Inside DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection()
05-06 11:18:16.579: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):start to get IP for host domain at time 1430921896581
05-06 11:18:16.579: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):finish to get IP for host domain at time 1430921896583, result number 1
05-06 11:18:16.579: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection()InetAddress.getAllByName length:1
05-06 11:18:16.614: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(4021): Ignore this event
05-06 11:18:16.629: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection() connsock Socket[address=/ip,port=443,localPort=35222]
05-06 11:18:16.714: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):Servers selected Ip address is : ip
05-06 11:18:17.004: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):HttpClientParams.isRedirecting(params) : true
05-06 11:18:17.004: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2(ApacheHTTPLog):this.redirectHandler.isRedirectRequested(response, context) : false
05-06 11:18:17.004: I/System.out(4021): pool-5-thread-2 calls detatch()
05-06 11:18:17.044: D/NONE(4021): Clearing notification subscriptions.
05-06 11:18:17.049: D/NONE(4021): Clearing tag notification subscriptions.
05-06 11:18:17.054: D/NONE(4021): Send new server notification token id.
05-06 11:18:17.059: D/GCMRegistrar(4021): resetting backoff for com.appname
05-06 11:18:17.059: V/GCMRegistrar(4021): Registering app com.appname of senders 15237827500
05-06 11:18:17.059: D/NONE(4021): Updating tag notification subscriptions.
05-06 11:18:17.069: D/CordovaLog(4021): file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js: Line 5688 : No matching configurations found from the server. Defaulting to local configuration
05-06 11:18:17.069: I/chromium(4021): [INFO:CONSOLE(5688)] "No matching configurations found from the server. Defaulting to local configuration", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js (5688)
05-06 11:18:17.074: D/NONE(4021): response [/apps/services/api/appname/android/query] success: /*-secure-
05-06 11:18:17.074: D/NONE(4021): {"statusCode":200,"errors":[],"isSuccessful":true,"Envelope":{"Body":{"Clearing_MobileResponse":{"Clearing_MobileResult":{"schema":{"id":"NewDataSet","element":{"complexType":{"choice":{"element":{"complexType":{"sequence":{"element":[{"name":"PROCESANDO_SOLICITUD","type":"xs:string","minOccurs":"0"},{"name":"ERROR","type":"xs:int","minOccurs":"0"}]}},"name":"TablaInfo"},"maxOccurs":"unbounded","minOccurs":"0"}},"MainDataTable":"TablaInfo","name":"NewDataSet","IsDataSet":"true","UseCurrentLocale":"true"},"msdata":"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata","xs":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema","xmlns":""},"diffgram":{"msdata":"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata","DocumentElement":{"TablaInfo":{"id":"TablaInfo1","hasChanges":"inserted","PROCESANDO_SOLICITUD":"OK","ERROR":"0","rowOrder":"0"},"xmlns":""},"diffgr":"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"}},"xmlns":"http:\/\/sa-webservices\/"}},"xsd":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema","soap":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2003\/05\/soap-envelope","xsi":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance"},"statusReason":"OK","WL-Authentication-Success":{"wl_anonymousUserRealm":{"userId":"09f4f163-c5ee-40d0-964a-4a15060abe42","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"09f4f163-c5ee-40d0-964a-4a15060abe42","deviceId":"09f4f163-c5ee-40d0-964a-4a15060abe42"}},"notificationSubscriptionState":{"tags":["Push.ALL"],"eventSources":[],"token":"APA91bFNWYtZp2DTdK4rMLrIKzvktSp64lFK3__AM-...","credentials":"15237827348"},"responseHeaders":{"X-AspNet-Version":"4.0.30319","Date":"Wed, 06 May 2015 14:18:49 GMT","Content-Length":"1316","Content-Type":"application\/soap+xml; charset=utf-8","Server":"Microsoft-IIS\/6.0","X-Powered-By":"ASP.NET","Cache-Control":"private, max-age=0"},"warnings":[],"responseTime":108,"totalTime":110,"info":[]}*/
05-06 11:18:17.099: E/ViewRootImpl(4021): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
05-06 11:18:17.154: D/mali_winsys(4021): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
05-06 11:18:17.519: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(4021): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
05-06 11:18:17.519: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(4021): GCM IntentService class: com.appname.GCMIntentService
05-06 11:18:17.519: V/GCMBaseIntentService(4021): Acquiring wakelock
05-06 11:18:17.539: V/GCMBaseIntentService(4021): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-4
05-06 11:18:17.539: D/GCMBaseIntentService(4021): handleRegistration: registrationId = APA91bFNWYtZp2DTdK4rMLrIKzvktSp64lFK3__AM-..., error = null, unregistered = null
05-06 11:18:17.539: D/GCMRegistrar(4021): resetting backoff for com.appname
05-06 11:18:17.544: V/GCMRegistrar(4021): Saving regId on app version 3
05-06 11:18:17.549: V/GCMBaseIntentService(4021): Releasing wakelock
05-06 11:18:17.549: D/GCMIntentService(4021): GCMIntentService.onRegistered in GCMIntentService.java:81 :: WLGCMIntentService: Registered at the GCM server with registration id APA91bFNWYtZp2DTdK4rMLrIKzvktSp64lFK3__AM-...
05-06 11:18:17.584: D/NONE(4021): onReadyToSubscribe
05-06 11:18:17.594: W/NONE(4021): Event source callback is already registered with alias: scoring
05-06 11:18:18.234: E/ViewRootImpl(4021): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
05-06 11:18:18.419: D/NONE(4021): cantidad: 1
05-06 11:18:19.089: D/NONE(4021): Piggybacking event transmission
05-06 11:18:19.099: D/NONE(4021): Flush called
05-06 11:18:48.674: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(4021): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
05-06 11:18:48.674: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(4021): GCM IntentService class: com.appname.GCMIntentService
05-06 11:18:48.674: V/GCMBaseIntentService(4021): Acquiring wakelock
05-06 11:18:48.684: V/GCMBaseIntentService(4021): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-5
05-06 11:18:48.699: V/GCMBaseIntentService(4021): Releasing wakelock
05-06 11:18:48.699: D/GCMIntentService(4021): GCMIntentService.onMessage in GCMIntentService.java:107 :: WLGCMIntentService: Received a message from the GCM server
05-06 11:18:48.709: W/GCMIntentService(4021): GCMIntentService.onMessage in GCMIntentService.java:114 :: Unable to update badge while received push notification, becasue failed to parse badge number null, badge must be an integer number.
05-06 11:18:48.714: D/push(4021): Push$1.onReceive in Push.java:91 :: Push: Queuing message for dispatch to javascript
05-06 11:18:48.719: D/push(4021): Push$1.onReceive in Push.java:97 :: Push: App on foreground and init completed. Add message from intent to pending: Message(alert=nueva notificacion, badge=1, sound=null, priority=0, visibility=1, redact=null, payload={"apellido":" ","tipoDoc":"DNI","alias":"scoring","lsmHasta":"","dictamen":"REINTENTO","prodOfrecer":"","nombre":" ","tipoCarga":"N","nroDoc":"33312","rechazo":"Reintente la consulta.","lsmDesde":"","docAPresentar":"","lc":""}, category=null, bridge=true)
05-06 11:18:48.719: D/push(4021): Push.dispatchPending in Push.java:395 :: Dispatching to javascript Message(alert=nueva notificacion, badge=1, sound=null, priority=0, visibility=1, redact=null, payload={"apellido":" ","tipoDoc":"DNI","alias":"scoring","lsmHasta":"","dictamen":"REINTENTO","prodOfrecer":"","nombre":" ","tipoCarga":"N","nroDoc":"33312","rechazo":"Reintente la consulta.","lsmDesde":"","docAPresentar":"","lc":""}, category=null, bridge=true)
05-06 11:23:18.494: D/CordovaActivity(4021): Paused the application!
05-06 11:23:18.494: D/CordovaWebView(4021): Handle the pause
05-06 11:23:18.499: D/WLClient(4021): WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityPaused in WLClient.java:1293 :: on activity paused com.appname.appname . activity count = 0
05-06 11:23:18.519: D/NONE(4021): Flush called
05-06 11:23:18.544: D/WLClient(4021): WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivitySaveInstanceState in WLClient.java:1305 :: on activity save instance state com.appname.appname
05-06 11:23:18.549: D/WLClient(4021): WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityStopped in WLClient.java:1317 :: on activity stopped com.appname.appname
```

Comment: What does push has to do with your adapter call? Add some context to your question. Provide your MobileFirst version and build number, provide your implementation code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling a method in the adapter with the property

```
securityTest="wl_unprotected"
```

Removed that solve my problem.